# Flutter How to fix no visible @interface for 'SKPaymentQueue' qonversion

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, in-app-purchase

Using the qonversion_flutter: 2.5.0 package for flutter android and ios. The app was working fine in debug for bith platforms. But now in release ony android is working since in release ios an error but not with much info. Just that could't build . I cleaned my project re downloaded pod files with removing all related files. Now the ios app in release and debug is nit working with the follwoing error :

```
 no visible
    @interface for 'SKPaymentQueue' declares the selector
    'presentCodeRedemptionSheet'
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] presentCodeRedemptionSheet];
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems an error in the qonversion pacakge for flutter. No ios experiance. What can be the solution
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you called `flutter pub get` command and then `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

Most probably an xcode version issue.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/81426

Update your xcode,

```
flutter clean
```

and rebuild, should fix it

dont forget to pod install as well